# Getting rid of 'Can't draw to closed window' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics

i have this program:

```
import graphics
import random
window = graphics.GraphWin("Dots", 700, 700)
while True:
  x = random.randint(0, 700)
  y = random.randint(0, 700)
  p = graphics.Point(x, y)
  p.draw(window)
window.close()
```

the code works fine; drawing lots of dots, but when i close it pressing the 'x' sign, it shows the error:

> GraphicsError: Can't draw to closed window

how can i get rid of it making the program stop drawing dots and go through the regular closing procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was:

```
while True:

    try:
        # Code to run
        x = random.randint(0, 700)
        y = random.randint(0, 700)
        p = graphics.Point(x, y)
        p.draw(window)

    except GraphicsError:
        # When the cross is clicked and the exception occurs
        break

win.close()
```

Be aware that other errors may get caught in this `try-except`.